# How do I set all display edges in a model to hard (in Maya 2017)?

Tags: maya, mel

How do I set all display edges in a model to hard (in Maya 2017)?

I found a **MEL script** in a different post that lets you select all hard edges

(**this one:** `polySelectConstraint -m 3 -t 0x8000 -sm 1;)`,

but I want to turn all display edges to hard, not just select them. I want to do this because I didn't build my model out of primitives and it's overly complex, **(importing from SketchUp)**. The only way I can think to do this is individually select each and every mesh component and set it manually. But I feel there must be a **MEL script** that might do the trick, does anyone know of one?

Answer (score 0):

the relevant command is [`polySoftEdge`](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2010help/Commands/polySoftEdge.html) -- if you set the angle to something lower than the angle between the faces the edge will be hard; if you set it to something higher it will be soft.